# Android studio - get collection from user in firebase using java

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the "bet" collection from the firebase database (on android studio, using java).
this is the collection
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Y1l.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rvp7.png)

,I got User class that has the fields
"full_name","email","password".
what should i do with the "bet" collection?
I tried

```
                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        db.collection("Users").document(UserID).get().addOnCompleteListener(task ->{
                            if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null){


                                String number_bet = task.getResult().getString("bet");
                            }
                        } );
```

It failed and i couldn't find any solutions
,I can access the other fields, for example

```
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        User user1 = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        if(user1 != null){
                    user_submit.setText(user1.bet_display);
                        }
                    }
```

all that i need is to get the drawn number (0-36) value(in that case String)

thanks!

Comment: Please show us what is inside "bet" node.

Comment: i have nothing inside it, i dont know how to store the elements there
its a roulette game, when user submit a bet the field bet added to firebase
i tried to add the fields to the user node but failed,
i tried to separate user and bet to two diffrent chart but filterd with same user_id
everything failed

Comment: The "bet" node is present in your database.

Comment: it is kind of a map, key-value (keys from 0-36) value starts at 0 
I added picture to the post

Comment: So you only want to get the content of the "bet" node?

Comment: yep, im drawing numbers from 0 - 36
after that i need to check the value of the drawn number in the "bet" node

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me.

```
                    DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                    reference.child(UserID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            String str2 = snapshot.child("bet").child(""+NUMBER).getValue().toString();                                                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
                    });
```

NUMBER is the path, it drawn every time..

just got to the right path by snapshot.child(some key).child(some key)....getValue().toString()